# InvalidSignatureException with AWS Kinesis Video Stream C#

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis

I am attempting to execute my own HTTP signed request since there is no SDK in C# for the PutMedia API for the AWS Kinesis Video Stream, but I am getting the following error message:

**StatusCode: 403, ReasonPhrase: 'Forbidden'**
**x-amzn-ErrorType: InvalidSignatureException:http://internal.amazon.com/coral/com.amazon.coral.service/**

Here is a gist of what my code looks like:

```
            var streamName = "audio-stream-test";
            var service = "kinesisvideo";
            var endpoint = GetPutMediaEndpoint(streamName);
            var host = GetHostFromEndpoint(endpoint);
            var region = GetRegionFromEndpoint(endpoint);

            var t = DateTime.UtcNow;
            var canonical_uri = $"{endpoint}/putMedia";

            var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, new Uri(canonical_uri));
            httpRequestMessage.Headers.Add("connection", "keep-alive");
            httpRequestMessage.Headers.Add("host", host);
            httpRequestMessage.Headers.Add("Transfer-Encoding", "chunked");
            httpRequestMessage.Headers.Add("user-agent", "AWS-SDK-KVS/2.0.2");
            httpRequestMessage.Headers.Add("x-amzn-fragment-acknowledgment-required", "1");
            httpRequestMessage.Headers.Add("x-amzn-fragment-timecode-type", "ABSOLUTE");
            httpRequestMessage.Headers.Add("x-amzn-producer-start-timestamp", (t - DateTime.MinValue).TotalMilliseconds.ToString());
            httpRequestMessage.Headers.Add("x-amzn-stream-name", streamName);
            httpRequestMessage.Headers.Add("x-amz-security-token", sessionToken);

            var byteArray = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
            var content = new ByteArrayContent(byteArray);
            httpRequestMessage.Content = content;

            var httpClient = new HttpClient();

            var aws4RequestSigner = new AWS4RequestSigner(accessKey, secretAccessKey);
            var signedHttpRequestMessage = aws4RequestSigner.Sign(httpRequestMessage, service, region).Result;
            var httpResponseMessage = httpClient.SendAsync(signedHttpRequestMessage);
```

[Screenshot of Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUonS.png)

I am using the Aws4RequestSigner NuGet package to sign the request. Any ideas what I am doing wrong here? Has anyone tried to use the AWS Kinesis Video Stream with C#/.NET successfully?

Answer (score 0):

Two potential issues with the pseudo-code.

1. If using session token then the request signing should include the session token as well not only access key/secret access key combination.
2. The body of the PutMedia is "endless" as it streams out as a realtime stream. As such, the data shouldn't be included in the signature calculation.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I have change the code to include the session token as part of the signature and also removed the data from the signature calculation. Unfortunately, still getting a 403 forbidden, invalidsignatureexception.

Comment: @mv18742n Could you please try to remove the following header: 'httpRequestMessage.Headers.Add("host", host); '. The C Producer SDK code is here: https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-video-streams-producer-sdk-cpp/blob/master/kinesis-video-c-producer/src/source/CurlApiCallbacks.c#L1993 which does similar things as in your code.

Comment: Okay I am finally getting 200 (OK). I had two errors: 1- the connection header is not part of the signing. 2 - as @N'Bayramberdiyev said, the PutMedia is "endless" and should not be sign as a matter of fact it should be added as "UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD". My issue now is that the actual "content" is not being added to the stream. I see the Put Connection from KVS but no data added. Any ideas? Thanks for all the help so far.

Answer (score 0):

This is answer to your question "the actual "content" is not being added to the stream. I see the Put Connection from KVS but no data added".

After you get 200 by setting http headers properly for the signing with below code, you need to have your content set in signedHttpRequestMessage.

var httpResponseMessage = httpClient.SendAsync(signedHttpRequestMessage);